Number of Intersection Points of two Plane Polynomial Curves over $\Bbb R$.
For two polynomials $f,g\in\Bbb R[x,y]$ is it always true that the number of intersection points of the graphs of $f$ and $g$ is at most $\deg(f)\deg(g)$?
Writing this out in standard notation, since $V(f)\cap V(g)=V((f,g))$ I really need an estimate of the zeros of the ideal $(f,g)$ over $\Bbb R$. While this is easy if $\Bbb R[x,y]$ is replaces by $\Bbb R[x]$ and one could just notice $\gcd(f,g)|fg$ and the number zeros of $(f,g)$ cannot exceed that of $fg$, how could one do it in polynomials rings in two variables?
I know the statement of Bezout's Theorem without the proof. Clearly the question is a corollary of Bezout's Theorem in two variables case over $\Bbb C$. If you could provide an easier proof of this theorem in the case of $k[x,y]$ where $k$ is algebraically closed that would be great. Also feel free to use any commutative algebra like results about noetherian rings, Jacobson rings, etc.

Yes, this is true, assuming you add the necessary assumption that $f$ and $g$ are coprime. You can read a proof of Bezout's theorem in a number of places, so I won't reproduce one here, and once you know the statement in the algebraically closed case, we can make some quick arguments to deduce the statement in the non-algebraically-closed case.
Suppose $f,g\in k[x,y]$ are two coprime polynomials. Then $f,g$ remain coprime in $\overline{k}[x,y]$, so we have $|V_{\overline{k}}(f,g)| \leq (\deg f)(\deg g)$ by the usual Bezout theorem, and as the set $V_k(f,g)$ admits a natural injection in to the set $V_{\overline{k}}(f,g)$ (just consider an intersection point with coordinates in $k^2$ as a point in $\overline{k}^2$), we get $|V_k(f,g)| \leq |V_{\overline{k}}(f,g)| \leq (\deg f)(\deg g)$.
